# What does the "full pixel mode" option do on Shadow of the Colossus HD?

Tags: ps3, shadow-of-the-colossus

Looking through the options, I saw "full pixel mode" as something you can enable/disable.  What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-ico-shadow-of-the-colossus-hd-collection):

> There's also a "full pixel" mode that liberates the PS3 version from the borders of the original game, giving the game much more real estate on-screen - boosted all the more by the move from the original's 4:3 aspect ratio to the full 16:9 widescreen experience.

It also seems to [eliminate overscan](http://forum.blu-ray.com/blu-ray-games-playstation-3/133679-ico-shadow-colossus-collection-out-week-10.html#post4841668), giving the sharpest possible picture on an HDTV.

Comment: So why would this feature be disabled? Are there any disadvantages (e.g. frame rate)?

Comment: @Alex There wouldn't be a noticable difference in frame rate, but some players would prefer to play the game with its original borders and aspect ratio. That being said, it was a developer decision to disable the feature by default, so you'd have to ask them.

Comment: Funny, this is what I thought it did before I asked but I didn't see any difference for some reason (no black border with it turned off).  It turns out I had left my TV on stretch mode, so it was automatically stretching out the black bars (whoops).